# C# exception: Key is not present in the dictionary

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary, keynotfoundexception

I got a little problem. Sometimes, when I try to call the following code, the remove methods throw an exception with the message "the key is not present in the dictionary".

```
private Dictionary<IPAddress, ARPHostEntry> dIPHostTable;
private Dictionary<MACAddress, ARPHostEntry> dMACHostTable;

public HostTable()
{
    dIPHostTable = new Dictionary<IPAddress, ARPHostEntry>();
    dMACHostTable = new Dictionary<MACAddress, ARPHostEntry>();
}

public void AddHost(ARPHostEntry arphEntry)
{
    lock (dMACHostTable)
    {
        if (dMACHostTable.ContainsKey(arphEntry.MAC))
        {
            dMACHostTable.Remove(arphEntry.MAC);
        }
        dMACHostTable.Add(arphEntry.MAC, arphEntry);
    }
    lock (dIPHostTable)
    {
        if (dIPHostTable.ContainsKey(arphEntry.IP))
        {
            dIPHostTable.Remove(arphEntry.IP);
        }
        dIPHostTable.Add(arphEntry.IP, arphEntry);
    }
}
```

The class ARPHostEntry is a simple calss which holds an IP-Address and an associated MAC-Address where both fiels in this class are read-only. 
The program is multi-threaded, but I lock the dictionarys in this class every time I use them.

I am helpless. Why do this exceptions occour?

with best regards

**Edit**

For clarification, the accepted answer is correct. The generated exception was an issue caused by cross-thread access to my dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Remove method shouldn't throw such exception, it should return false if key not found (See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kabs04ac%28VS.85%29.aspx)).
Instead of removing and adding, why don't you try updating the value of the key?

Comment: O_O. 

Okay, i will re-check this. 
Strange. 

And I will try to update only the value. Thanks.

Comment: I'm probably a little late but I fixed it the way you suggested. Together with a cleaner multihtreading-model (ISyncrhonizeInvoke) in the calling class it works now.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from your example if you're truly sharing the host tables across threads. Shouldn't the private host tables also be static?

Comment: No, I need multiple instances of this class for multiple network interfaces which are shared with many other objecty implementing higher layers and many threads.